# Add non-JS (transpiled) files in a CRNA project

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app

**In a React Native (Expo) project,** created with `create-react-native-app`, I want to **add some non-JS files**, which will be transpiled<sup>1</sup> to JS, to be included in the regular codebase of the project.

Now, I'd like to have the normal `npm start` task treat the non-JS files **as "first class"** part of the project — specifically:

- **auto-detect changes** in the non-JS source files;
- after the changes are detected, **run an extra "build" script** which would transpile<sup>1</sup> the non-JS sources to `.js` files;
- finally, **bundle** the resulting `.js` files (coming from the transpilation<sup>1</sup>) together with the rest of the "normal" JS files, and send/serve them to the Expo client.

In other words, I'd like to be able to write/modify my non-JS code with similar ease of use and fast feedback loop as when I write/modify the JS code in the project.

**How can I configure such behavior in a CRNA project?**

Is it even possible? If I understand correctly, I'd prefer not to "eject" the project, as I don't want to lose the automation etc. of a CRNA project. (Such stuff is being lost during "ejection", no?)

---

<sup>1</sup> *a.k.a. compiled, compile, ...*